# Overriding virtual functions in a mutually exclusive manner

Tags: c++, oop

```
class EventListener
{
public:
    virtual void onEvent (std::string message) = 0;
    virtual void onEvent (std::string message, int eventCode) = 0;
};

class CustomEventListener : public EventListener
{
public:
    void onEvent(std::string message) {};
    void onEvent(std::string message, int eventCode) {}; // I want this to throw an error
};
```

I want to make it so that overriding one of the overloaded functions excludes the user from overriding the other, potentially throwing a compile-time exception. Is this possible ?

The reason why I want to keep both virtual functions in the interface is to maintain backwards-compatibility with users who already use the first function extensively in their application and I don't want to force them to use the second, newer one.

Making both functions non-pure is not really an option, because I want to force the user to override one of them.

Comment: My C++ is rusty: I don't think you can leave either one unimplemented if you add `= 0` to both, can you? How do you know which one has been overridden and so which is safe to call at run time?

Comment: How do you know which one the user provided? I'm pretty sure you need to provide default implementations and call both anyways, so if the user overrides both nothing bad happens. Also you gain nothing but hatred for making this a pure virtual function, if someone doesn't want to override `onEvent` then they don't get the event, why force them?

Comment: Adding another pure virtual function is not exactly backwards compatible. The users will need to implement it (even trivially) and recompile their classes.

Comment: I don't see any way to enforce your constraint, either at compile time or at runtime, without some very, very nasty unportable hacks (such as checking vtable addresses).

Comment: I agree that in most cases using pure virtual and forcing the user to implement all methods isn't the way to go. As a side note: If the class registers the listener itself, then the class can inherit the listener as private and add the method overrides as private.

Comment: if users only implement one specific `onEvent` overload, they won't be able to instantiate their subclasses since they will remain abstract

Comment: @nwp You're right: as far as I know there is simply to way to determine if a child class has overridden a method of a parent class. With all the answers given here I suppose the best call would be to just get rid of the first virtual function.

Comment: If they are both pure, the user has to override both. What you want is not possible and not readonable. Implement one functions in terms of the other in the base class, and ket the user override one or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make it so that overriding one of the overloaded functions excludes the user from overriding the other, potentially throwing a compile-time exception. Is this possible ?

No. It's not possible to conditionally prevent overriding of a function depending on other overrides. At least not in standard c++.

> The reason why I want to keep both virtual functions in the interface is to maintain backwards-compatibility with users who already use the first function extensively in their application and I don't want to force them to use the second, newer one.

If you add a new pure virtual function to the interface, then all inheriting classes that don't yet implement the new function will become abstract. That will break backwards compatibility.

Preventing the user from implementing one of them would not help. Instead it only prevents them from making a concrete class that inherits the interface.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it wouldn't be possible, but I wasn't 100% sure. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Why not enforce to override only one of them with further implementations:

```
class CustomEventListener : public EventListener {
public:
    virtual void onEvent(std::string message) {};

private: // <<<<<<<<
    // I want this to throw an error
    virtual void onEvent(std::string message, int eventCode) { 
        throw std::runtime_error("Deprecated");
    }
};
```

Comment: The idea is that users themselves will implement the interface so that they chose what happens when events are triggered. Sorry, I made a mistake when writing `CustomEventListener` by making the functions there virtual too.

Comment: @Catalin The function overrides/implementations need to be `virtual` actually. You may try offering your client classes a different interface using the [template function pattern](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwidssDDguXHAhWM1ywKHQutB60&usg=AFQjCNFPnuiy0gyX5wGz85DenVJhDGPhEw&sig2=cKj1lVra4i_NIPgEB5TyWQ)

Comment: @Catalin since those functions override virtual functions, they're implicitly virtual whether you've marked them so explicitly or not.

Answer (score 0):

As user2079303 answered, you can't do it like you suggested.

However, you may do some walkaround which could do the trick you want to achieve.

```
class EventListener
{
public:
    virtual void onEvent (std::string message)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Deprecated");
    }
    virtual void onEvent (std::string message, int eventCode)
    {
        onEvent(message);
    }
};
```

Old classes can still override only the first method.

```
class CustomEventListener : public EventListener
{
public:
    void onEvent(std::string message) {};
};
```

New classes are forced (thus only by the exception) to override one of them, so they can look like this:

```
class CustomEventListener : public EventListener
{
public:
    void onEvent(std::string message, int eventCode) {};
};
```

Unfortunately users can also override both of them, but there is nothing you can do about it.

To correctly handle this situation, you should call the second method in your code.